# autofill value with the checkbox

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex

I have created interactive grid in oracle apex now I want to make checkbox when I marked it so check by and checked date should be autofill with the SysData and user can someone tell me what I should apply code behind this.

Comment: IF CHECKED = 'Y' THEN
  CHECK_BY:= v('APP_USER');
 CHECK_DATE:= SYSDATE.
END IF; I used this code in dynamic action first i set event is change then set value write this code in pl/SQL block.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create dynamic action with two "Set value" *actions*.

- dynamic action event: change
- 1st Set value:

  - set type: PL/SQL expression
  - expression: `sysdate`
  - affected elements:

    - type: column
    - column: `date_column` (or whatever its name is)
- 2nd Set value:

  - set type: PL/SQL expression
  - expression: `:APP_USER`
  - affected elements:

    - type: column
    - column: `user_name` (or whatever its name is)

---

Another option is to create database trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_tab
  before insert or update on your_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.date_column := sysdate;
  :new.user_column := v('APP_USER');
end;
/
```

Comment: I'd definitely go for the database trigger if that is an option. Capturing SYSDATE on the client side is never accurate, since it captures the value on click and not on save and usually lacks precision. Note that the trigger probably needs some code to capture the column change from "unchecked" to "checked" value so it is not updating every time.